# What is the best way of templating in ExtJs 5?

Tags: handlebars.js, template-engine, extjs5, hogan.js

What is the best way of templating in ExtJs: Handlebar.js,Hogan.js,Mustache.js
or tpl provided by ExtJs?

Answer (score 1):

The templating provided in Ext.Component isn't the friendliest or most powerful templating tool ever invented.

That said, it does have excellent integration with the DOM, enabling direct access to elements created in the template, and decent integration with the ViewModel for passing data into the template (one-way only, unfortunately).

I would suggest starting with the ExtJS templating and see if it meets your needs, before trying to integrate a third-party templating tool.